# Django-Admin: how to use one field for both inlinemodel and model

Tags: django, django-admin

Hello i am working in django admin panel, i am making 2 models

workflow, and workflow stages, both has filed company

workflow is inline inside of workflow

my question is how to make all of the workflow stages uses the same company field up in the workflow.

```
class WorkflowStageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = WorkflowStage
    extra = 7


class WorkflowAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [WorkflowStageInline, ]
    list_display = ('id', 'company', 'is_template')
    list_display_links = ('id', 'company')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add these two methods to your `WorkflowStageInline` class:

```
def get_formset(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    self.parent_obj = obj
    return super().get_formset(request, obj, **kwargs)

def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    field = super().formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, request, **kwargs)
    if db_field.name == 'company':
        field.initial = self.parent_obj.company if self.parent_obj else None
    return field
```

`get_formset()` adds the parent object to each inline instance. `formfield_for_dbfield()` uses that parent object to populate the initial value of the `company` field.